# API request validity interval is out-of-date issue on some devices

Tags: android, ssl

I face Issue when I try to connect to my APIs server with wrong device date
the request throws internet connection error with the following exceptions:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not determine revocation status

but this behavior not happened in all devices with the same date but it also works within a range of the wrong dates almost a day before and after the current date.

this issue is always happening on devices from android 8.0 and above, but not happens on android 7.0.
I notice this issue happens according to the wrong date, but I can't understand the reason for this.
So I want to understand what happens and the reason for this, also the best practice to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Set the proper system time on my device and it works.

Go to `Settings` > `System` > `Date & Time` > Set it to `Automatic date & time`

Comment: beautiful~       ...............

Answer (score 0):

The ones which deem the certificate unreliable are actually working properly.

There is nothing to solve, except installing a server-side certificate with a validity term, which matches the device date. Disabling certificate validation is not a solution, but it's stupid - because it would permit expired and revoked certificates, undermining the CA. For example: if someone gets hold of the private key, you'd have no way to revoke the certificate, when accepting revoked certificates. This might be acceptible on a private network, but on the internet, you'd be shooting yourself into the feet.

Just see [Browsers and Certificate Validation](https://www.ssl.com/article/browsers-and-certificate-validation/), paragraph "Certification Path Validation Algorithm".

And [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) offers SSL certificates free of charge, with 3 months validity.